# Redirect on a different location and port in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, redirect

To redirect a user to a different page, we usually do:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: '/test'
});
res.end();
```

What if I want to redirect him on a different port? I tried to add a field 'Port' but it seems to don t work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the full URL:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://anotherdomain.com:8888/some/path'
});
res.end();
```

Comment: Already tried, when another node.js server try to follow this, he don t connect the right way and fail to connect.

Comment: I m a idiot, the port wasn t send when I tried to follow the redirect. Your answer work.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the 'http'